# Aggregating and uglifying JavaScript in a Git pre-commit hook

Tags: git, continuous-integration, githooks, uglifyjs

I'm using `ready.js` to aggregate JavaScript files into an `all.js` file (without [Google's Closure Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Closure_Tools#Closure_Compiler)) and am then using `uglify-js` to minify and obfuscate the code. I'd like to do all of this in a pre-commit hook.

However, I think I'm doing something wrong.

My `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
readyjs ~/Sites/backbone/js/javascripts/ ~/Sites/backbone/js/ --nojslint -o "underscore.js, backbone.js" --nocompiler
uglifyjs -nm -o ~/Sites/backbone/js/all.min.js ~/Sites/backbone/js/all.js
# Commit
exit
```

Should I not be using simple Bash here? Is there something else I'm doing wrong? This step seems to be skipped entirely.

Comment: Would that be that git doesn't know where to find those commands? Try specifying full paths to those binaries, rather than just stating the commands themselves.

Comment: @favoretti Good idea, but still didn't work. I tested them with `/usr/bin/readyjs` which worked on the command line just fine, but failed in the hook.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My psychic powers suggest that your script isn't executable; try doing

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

Comment: Exactly right. Now if your psychic powers could tell me why the hook is not executable by default when doing `git commit`.

Comment: well, because you created that file yourself and new files are created with permissions specified by the mounted file systems file mode creation mask (umask) which should never create new files with the executable flag because most files are not :)

Comment: The follow-up (Stack Overflow) question is *[Why is my Git pre-commit hook not executable by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598639/).*