# Why is my Git pre-commit hook not executable by default?

Tags: git, githooks

If you see the accepted answer in:
[Aggregating and uglifying JavaScript in a Git pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598246/aggregating-and-uglifying-javascript-in-a-git-pre-commit-hook), you'll see that I had to do a `chmod +x` on my pre-commit hook to get it to work.

Why is this not executable by Git by default?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Because files are not executable by default; they must be set to be executable.

The sample files from a `git init` are all executable; if it's copied or renamed to a non-sample file, it will retain the original file's `x` flag.

New files will be created with current defaults. In your case, view those defaults with `umask`:

```
$ umask
0022
```

By default, new files won't be `u+x` unless explicitly set to be.

Comment: I'm running git v1.7.6 on Mac OS X Lion. I'd done `git init` to reinitialize the repo and that still didn't work. I edited the file in TextMate, which might be the problem, but still doesn't explain why `git init` wouldn't do the `chmod u+x` properly.

Comment: @JoshSmith `git init` only creates sample hooks, not actual ones. I'm running 1.7.5.4 on Lion, and 1.7.0 on Ubuntu--they both create the sample files as `u+x`--I guess I'm a little skeptical it isn't on yours.

Comment: If nothing else I discovered my Linux box is running an old-ish version of git.

Comment: So am I going to have to `chmod` every single time I modify the hook?

Comment: @JoshSmith Uh, no, once it's set, you shouldn't need to change it again.

Comment: I meant more when I do such a hook in any new git repo. That's going to get annoying.

Comment: @JoshSmith Then change your `umask` setting, and hope you never accidentally execute something you didn't mean to. Not that typing "chmod u+x" is all that onerous. Or copy the samples that are already set.

Comment: the bit 2 is for write permission, the only thing that `umask` set to `022` does is to prevent new files to be writable by the group and other user, nothing to do with the execute bit which is 1.

Comment: @JeanPaul If you re-read you’ll see that the “umask” example is to show example defaults, which are the defaults for new files.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry I don't get the point, with a umask of 022 new files won't be g+w and o+w, that's all. I don't see the link with the executable permission.

Comment: @JeanPaul There *is* no link with *my* umask results; I showed how to get the current `umask`.

Comment: ok but why talking about umask if umask has nothing to do with the problem? the problem can only happen if the user executable bit is set in the umask like `0133`, but i wonder who sets a umask like this and we don't understand this from your explanations

Answer (score 134):

My context - web development Node.js. I needed to add husky functionality, but got an error, probably to the disk access. This helped in my situation:

```
chmod ug+x .husky/*
chmod ug+x .git/hooks/*
```

Comment: Yeah, only this worked for me.

Comment: From *"[What is Husky?](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-commit-hooks-to-git-with-husky-to-automate-code-tasks/#what-is-husky)"*: *"Husky is a tool that allows us to easily wrangle Git hooks and run the scripts we want at those stages."*

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Why does it work? Why is *group* required? What is this *"husky"* thingy (for instance, I only have *dot* folders *".git"* and *".vscode"* in my repository)? What are the security implications of this change? What was context - some kind web development? Node.js? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66757359/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 31):

> I had to do a `chmod +x` on my pre-commit hook to get it to work

The problem is to realize that it was not executable in the first place.
That will be easier with Git 2.15.x/2.16 (Q1 2018)

See [commit f805a00](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f805a00a396ee91599902cebe55620b2a4c813b9) (06 Oct 2017) by [Damien Marié (`mdamien`)](https://github.com/mdamien).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 130b512](https://github.com/git/git/commit/130b512e62dd4cdd4c5d35700438b19b81cec00e), 06 Nov 2017)</sup>

> ### `run-command`: add hint when a hook is ignored
>
> When an hook is present but the file is not set as executable then git will
>   ignore the hook.
>   **For now this is silent which can be confusing**.
>
> This commit adds this warning to improve the situation:

```
hint: The 'pre-commit' hook was ignored because it's not set as executable.
hint: You can disable this warning with `git config advice.ignoredHook false`
```

> To allow the old use-case of enabling/disabling hooks via the executable flag a new setting is introduced: `advice.ignoredHook`.

Comment: Running from root of project directory, `chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit`  worked for me on macOS 10.13.3.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh That is the idea indeed. The hint could be more explicit.

Answer (score 8):

Just as a reference, after making the file executable, if that appears in git file changes because of file mode changes, the following would work: (tried in Ubuntu/Linux)

```sh
chmod ug+x .husky/pre-commit # make file executable
git config core.filemode false # to ignore file mode changes
```

Reference: [How do I remove files saying "old mode 100755 new mode 100644" from unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1257613/8915198)

Comment: Running this command `chmod ug+x .husky/pre-commit` solved problem on WSL windows (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 7):

I was able to solve it by just running the command below.

```bash
chmod ug+x .husky/*
```

I init `husky` in `Windows`. After that, the problem occurred in WSL, and it is probably a problem that was not created considering the file permissions of `Linux` at the time of init in `Windows`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same symptoms, but a totally different cause:

In addition to setting the right permission bits via `chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit`, please make sure your *file system* is mounted in a way that allows those changes. This can, e.g., be an issue when you have a dual-boot system where you are working on an `ntfs-3g` mounted Windows drive under Linux.

You can fix it by changing the default permissions in `/etc/fstab` or the [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved this issue by running the below command

```
chmod ug+x .husky/*
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when I created "pre-commit" manually. The approach with chmod might work, but it is a workaround and the issue might appear on another machine.

I fixed it by properly recreating "pre-commit" with the following command:

`npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "npm run lint"`

Comment: This is the best answer. Use `husky add` instead of manually creating the file.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an add-on answer, here is the function, you can use for initializing a Git repository, which automatically makes hooks executables; you should put it in `.bashrc` or a file you source when you start your terminal. The story is below :)

```
ginit () {
    git init
    gitpath=`git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree --show-toplevel | head -1`
    chmod u+x "$gitpath"/.git/hooks/*
    for submodule in "$gitpath"/.git/modules/*; do
        chmod u+x "$submodule"/hooks/*
    done
}
```

I was annoyed by the same thing as you. I do not want to remember that I have to make all hooks executables every time I initialize a repository. Plus, when you use [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), their hooks are not in `.git/hooks`, but in `.git/modules/NameOfSubmodule/hooks`, and these should be made executables too.

Answer (score 0):

The original template hook file must be executable.

In my case, it was a custom hook missing the executable bit:

```
$ git config init.templateDir
~/.git_template
$ stat -c "%A" ~/.git_template/hooks/pre-commit 
-rw-r--r--
$ chmod u+x ~/.git_template/hooks/pre-commit
```

Now the `pre-commit` hook created on `git init` or `git clone` is properly set as executable:

```
$ git init hook-exec
$ stat -c "%A" hook-exec/.git/hooks/pre-commit 
-rwxrwxr-x
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory