# Gitolite post-receive hook not executable anymore after each gitolite-admin push

Tags: git, permissions, hook, gitolite

I can't find *any* posts/articles on how to do this properly -- usually that means you're using it wrong, so I thought I'd ask here to check :)

I'm using Gitolite and it's working perfectly. I've implemented a common post-receive hook to be notified when one of my team members pushes a new commit, which I activated for their repos. The problem I'm having is, after each push (regardless of if the hook has changed or not) the file is overwritten with and gets the following permissions:

```
rwel@ve-git:~$ ls -la /home/git/.gitolite/hooks/common/
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 2 git git  4096 Jul  3 13:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 git git  4096 May  1 15:41 ..
-rw------- 1 git git 21002 Jul  3 13:23 post-receive
-rwxr-xr-x 1 git git   308 May 15 16:24 update
```

So, each time I do a `gitolite-admin rwel$ git push origin`, I then have to logon to the git server and manually do `sudo chmod a+x /home/git/.gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you using gitolite V2 (or g2, with gl-xxx commands) or Gitolite V3 (or g3) with `bin/gitolite` script?

Comment: look at serverfault: http://serverfault.com/q/221978 and http://serverfault.com/q/26954 --- dunno if i should post that as an answer though

Comment: @VonC: sorry, forgot to mention. V3.

Comment: @helt: those are both not answers for me. The `UMASK` is no good, as the owner doesn't even get x permissions (with a umask of 0). The other post (I think) explains how to set the permissions, but not how to keep them set correctly, right?

Comment: What does your Linux system 'umask' return? (I ask after looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8598684/6309)

Comment: The umask on the Git server is `0022`.

Comment: Did you resolve this question?

Comment: Yes, we resolved this by setting a cronjob that resets the permissions every minute. Couldn't find a better way unfortunately... I still find it strange that no one else has run into this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I [had the same Problem](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gitolite/B4nTny5nXuo/aDkW_a1swGAJ). Short answer is:

Check out the gitolite-admin repository on a unix machine, `chmod +x` your file and push it.

From now the file is executable, even when the repo is cloned on windows (since [cloning on windows sets core.fileMode=false](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html))